# Separate "duplicate lines" by empty line

Tags: sed, awk, text-formatting

My input is something like this:

```
fruit  apple word
fruit  lemon
fruit  orange other word
meat  ham word
vegetable  salad other
vegetable  lettuce more
```

How can I separate duplicate lines by an empty line, based on the first word? Like this:

```
fruit  apple word
fruit  lemon other word
fruit  orange word

meat ham word

vegetable  salad other
vegetable  lettuce more
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that it's possible to have spaces after the first word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic command you can tailor to your individual needs.

```
awk '{print $0 > $1}' inputfile
```

EDIT: Apologies, I just realised I misread your question, this is not the correct answer, though you could 'rejoin' the files with the blank lines easily enough

Here is a possible solution

```
for file in $(awk '{print $1; print $0 > $1}' data.txt | sort | uniq)
do
  cat $file
  echo
  rm $file
done > output.txt
```

Solution just using awk, if the file is pre-sorted:

```
awk '{a=$1; if (b != "" && a != b) {printf "\n";}; print $0; b = a}' inputfile
```

Reworked after comments by don_crissti (thanks!)

```
awk '{if (a != "" && a != $1) {printf "\n";}; print $0; a = $1}' inputfile
```

Comment: It works perfecty (used the last one), thanks!

Comment: Good point, could just just $1 and a. instead of a and b.

Comment: `awk 'a&&$1!=a{print ""}a=$1'`

Comment: You guys are all awesome, what if i want to remove the first word, assuming that i know its lenght is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

The **sed** solution can be

```
sed '
    /^\n/!{                             #if line do not starts from \newline 
        N                               #attach next line
        /^\(\w\+\b\).*\n\1/! s/\n/\n\n/ #if 1st word not a same insert \newline
    }
    P                                   #print 1st line (before \newline)
    D                                   #remove 1st line, return to start
    '
```

Answer (score 1):

another `awk` solution, assumes sorted input as shown in sample input

```
$ cat ip.txt 
fruit  apple word
fruit  lemon
fruit  orange other word
meat  ham word
vegetable  salad other
vegetable  lettuce more
```

Note: Order of condition checking matters.

```
$ awk '!seen[$1]++ && NR>1{printf "\n"} 1' ip.txt 
fruit  apple word
fruit  lemon
fruit  orange other word

meat  ham word

vegetable  salad other
vegetable  lettuce more
```

Similar solution in `perl`

```
$ perl -ane 'print "\n" if !$seen{$F[0]}++ && $. > 1; print' ip.txt 
fruit  apple word
fruit  lemon
fruit  orange other word

meat  ham word

vegetable  salad other
vegetable  lettuce more
```